# React Router, Getting location in nested child

Tags: react-router

With the `withRouter` HOC mentioned in
https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v2.4.0.md, is there a way to get `location` info?

Or do we still need to use our own context provider and hoc to access it?

Answer (score 0):

`location` is one of the props that [`withRouter`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.2/modules/withRouter.js#L37) injects into your component.

```js
const withRouter(({ location }) => (
  <div>You are here: {location.pathname}</div>
))
```

Comment: oh really? I thought withRouter only gives me this.props.router, Thanks!